# Not able to type in input textboxes in AC3 when attempt the scene in the second time

Tags: actionscript-3

1.click "sigma"
2.type number in input
3.click "solve"
4.click "back"
5.click "sigma" again
6.and now can't type the number in blanket
please tell if you know how to fix it please.
[Download here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/brai272fftfzeee/winrar-x64-520.exe)

Comment: Could you PLEASE explain what is your PROBLEM ?

Comment: on second time it can't input number in same sence

Comment: Could you show us your code to more understand ? Do you know that the link attached to your question is simply a winrar setup ?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/xeydbq2mdjajb15/AMT.rar

Answer (score 0):

Try always when asking for help, to explain your problem and show your code to give others the ability to help you.

To navigate ( go to ) between frames, you can use [gotoAndStop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop%28%29) or [gotoAndPlay](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay%28%29). If frames are in the same scene you can just do :

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button_onPress);
function button_onPress(event:MouseEvent):void {

    gotoAndStop(frame);    // or gotoAndPlay(frame);

}
```

Otherwise ( different scenes ) :

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button_onPress);
function button_onPress(event:MouseEvent):void {

    gotoAndStop(frame, scene);    // or gotoAndPlay(frame, scene);

}
```

And in both cases, you don't need to add an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener to your buttons to do that, and that's why you got that strange behavior which block typing text into your text fields because your animation is doing an infinite looping between the 1st and 5th frame.

Hope that can help.